# return *this c++

Tags: c++, void, return-type

if you have a clear() function that clears all elements in an array, do you use the void type or the referens to the type you are working with and returning *this.

Ex.

```
void Vector<T>::clear() {   
}
```

or

```
Vector& Vector<T>::clear(){
    return *this
}
```

I don't really understand when to return "this" and when to use void type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume returning `*this` is useful to chain API calls. `obj.doSomething().doSomethingElseAfterwards()`. So calls where chaining is useful, such as `add` are good candidates for `*this`. And methods where chaining is not very useful might return `void`.

Personally I'm not fond of this chaining style, but many people like the fluent APIs this allows.

Answer (score 4):

It's up to you.

For reference, [`std::vector::clear`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/clear/) returns `void`.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, there's no especially good reason to return the current object that I can think of, other than to enable dubious code like

```
myVector.clear().add(somethingNew);
```

Comment: What exactly is dubious about that? There are many places where one might want to do something like that. Factory objects, for example; that way, you can do: `Factory().Setting1(...).Setting2(...).Construct()` and get the object that needs to be made. All with a temporary. C++-based DESL's live and breath this stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I think i got it now. :)

Comment: @Nicol: some people like this; some people absolutely hate it. Personally I'm somewhere in the middle, but given the wide range of opinions, I try not to use this pattern unless it's already established in a given codebase.